# How to convert (downgrade) a .bib from Jabref-4.x back to Jabref-3.8.2 format?

Tags: bibtex, incompatibility, conversion, jabref

Jabref-4.1 is still not as stable as Jabref-3.8 was. Jabref stores some metadata such as groups in comments of the Bibtex database.

Jabref-4.x changed the file format unfortunately. I am not sure, if it was just the format how groups are saved.

How to convert a .bib database on a Linux system from the Jabref-4.x format back to the old format used in the final version 3.8.2?

Is there any feature which will get lost, because it was not known in the old file format?

Update: Thank you for the helpful comments so far. I upvoted several already. I will review now within the next days, perhaps my question is invalid or needs improvement.

Comment: @Mico  I have found many similar Jabref questions and even a jabref tag. I think it fits here better than in Unix&Linux.sx. But I will ask now in the tex.sx chat

Comment: @Mico I think this is on topic.

Comment: @AlanMunn - Thanks. I've deleted my earlier comment.

Comment: Please outline which issues you encounter when opening the 4.2 bib file with 3.8.2. The new groups format was introduced in JabRef 3.4 (see https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/blob/v3.8.2/CHANGELOG.md#34--2016-06-02), so there should not be any issues when working with 3.8.2.

Comment: Please join us for JabRef improvment at the [JabCon](https://jabcon.jabref.org/) in Dresden. 

Comment: I haven't moved on to version 4 of `JabRef` yet, so I don't know if there is any new format. But from `JabRef 2.9` to `3.8` the format differences are due to two things:

1. The coding, you must verify that it is correct. For ease of use, I always work in `utf8`, but I don't know if that helps you or suits your workflow.
2. The reference types you are using, you can do it with traditional `bibtex` or with `biblatex`.

Comment: I suspect that your problem is with encoding rather than `JabRef`, so I suggest you open your `.bib` file in a text editor and see the first two lines, it tells you that it was created with `JabRef`, its version and encoding.

Otherwise, it would be a great help if you detail the error you are getting.

Comment: Is there any news here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bib file in v3.8.2 is just slightly different from that in v4.1. The only difference is in `@Comment{jabref-meta`

To downgrade the bib file into the format compatible with v3.8.2, only 3 replacements need to be done. They are:

1. `grouping` -> `groupstree`
2. `StaticGroup` -> `ExplicitGroup`
3. remove all occurrences of `\;1\;\;\;`

---

FYI, in my v3.8.2 bib file, the group information is associated with entries---the `groups` field of an entry records the associated group(s) (separated by comma). The group comment just stores the hierarchical structure.

e.g.

```
@Article{LEcuyer-2007a,
  author     = {L'Ecuyer, Pierre and Simard, Richard},
  title      = {TestU01: A C Library for Empirical Testing of Random Number Generators},
  journal    = {ACM Trans. Math. Softw.},
  year       = {2007},
  volume     = {33},
  number     = {4},
  pages      = {22:1--22:40},
  month      = aug,
  doi        = {10.1145/1268776.1268777},
  groups     = {PRNG},
  numpages   = {40},
  publisher  = {ACM},
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Eli4ph for the correct answer. Here is a short bash script for the conversion, if you have the same problem. Please do not forget to upvote Eli4ph's answer.

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i 's/grouping/groupstree/g' $1
sed -i 's/StaticGroup/ExplicitGroup/g' $1
sed -i 's|\\;1\\;\\;\\;||g' $1
```